# Why are default spamassassin rules not being applied to emails we generate?

Tags: email, spamassassin, spam-filter

My company uses a standalone spam-assassin install to test marketing emails, however, mail originating from us does not seem to run the full gamut of test.
 For example, Spam assassin has a default rule that flags messages that contain the phrase `Dear [Something]`, and it properly flags spam that I feed it.It does not, however, apply that same rule to in house email I send it.

Is it possible that spam assassin has white-listed us somehow, perhaps because the mail originates in the same domain as the server or receiver?

I believe most of the recent spamassassin questions have been mine, so thanks for bearing with me as I figure this out!

Chance

**EDIT** Details on our SA setup:
We are piping the emails into the CL with `spamc -R < test_email.eml`
Identical results testing as root or a user, no user_prefs file

Comment: Are you logged in as root when doing this, or are you in as a user?  If you are in as a user, do you have an user_prefs for that user?

Answer (score 0):

Spamassassin can whitelist your domain, but it generally does not (spammers love to forge it).  It also has a mechanism for trusting your mail server that might be the issue.  Can you provide more details on how you are testing?  Are you using SA with a mail server, or just piping your mail into the commandline version of it?

Comment: We are piping the emails into the CL with spamc -R < test_email.eml (adding to the question as well for reference)

Answer (score 0):

Try "cat test_email.eml | spamassassin -D" for a more verbose output of SA.